# HTTPClient causing app to force close

Tags: android, android-emulator, httpclient

I get this error on my Android emulator:

Sorry
The application has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again. [Force Close]

I think the code that is creating the error is this:
**HttpClient client = new HttpClient();**

I have imported the following from JARS:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
```

Any idea?  Is there a way to get more details on what the error is?  The message described above isn't very helpful...

**Stacktrace:**

I've looked at this and I think this is the problem.  (it was too long to post all on here..)

```
E/dalvikvm(  757): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient', referenced from method com.projectNoble.androidClient.serverComms.initCommunication

W/dalvikvm(  757): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 46 (Lorg/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient;) in Lcom/projectNoble/androidClient/serverComms;

W/dalvikvm(  757): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

W/dalvikvm(  757): VFY:  rejected Lcom/projectNoble/androidClient/serverComms;.initCommunication ()Ljava/lang/String;

W/dalvikvm(  757): Verifier rejected class Lcom/projectNoble/androidClient/serverComms;

D/AndroidRuntime(  757): Shutting down VM
```

**Source Code**

Can be found at bottom of this page:
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

Comment: post your stacktrace and code...

Comment: Yeah, type adb logcat, and get the actual stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you get to stacktrace?

Code wise I have commented it all out and it still occurs on the first line: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Thanks

Comment: if you are using Eclipse look for Logcat option

Comment: Thanks for info.  Adding stack trace now.  Sorry its long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What jars you've imported from ? Apache client is part of android

Correct package

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

Remove your jars and use only libraries from the SDK

Comment: I downloaded JAR from apache and imported them.

Comment: thats not necessary. use the approache from Alex

Comment: Please use base components provided in SDK - full list of packages are here
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html You don't want to bundle something that already provided by OS.

Comment: Thanks Alex.

I've deleted the JARS I was refering to and I now use:

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

I'm still getting "Cannot find symbol" though for DefaultHttpClient, which is strange as its mentioned here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: you do have this import right ? 
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; if so could you update your stack trace in the question ? It seems to be NetBeans is not the best IDE for android development.

Comment: I've been having problems with Eclipse, where it kept giving me a runtime error...

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor "HttpClient()".

Maybe you want this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

really, though, if you want to configure it at all, etc, you can't pass an empty constructor.  Read the documentation for the different values you can pass.

Also, when you ask a question on stackoverflow, you'll get a lot more help if you post your code, and the full stacktrace of the error you're getting.  You can get the stacktrace from `adb logcat`, or from in eclipse.

Comment: I tried "HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();"

and netbeans says:

Cannot find symbol.

Comment: Then you are missing an import statement. Here is a sample project showing the use of `DefaultHttpClient`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/

Comment: His import is wrong  because he brought jars from apache directly to the project